# App crashes on Launch when made as system application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, java-native-interface, native, dji-sdk

I developed an application that uses **DJI SDK**. When installed as an system application it crashes on Launch because its not able to load the libraries. It works fine when installed as normal application.

Steps followed to make system application

1)Rooted the device

2)Copied the .apk file to system/app directory

3)Rebooted the device

4)App was installed as default application but crashed on Launch

After commenting out the following line related to DJI SDK and followed the same steps as above. It worked fine as system app.

```
       Helper.install(context);
```

The implementation of Helper class which is in DJI SDK is as below:

```
    public static void install(Application app) {
    Object var1 = null;

    try {
        System.loadLibrary("DexHelper_sdk");
        if (PPATH != null) {
            System.load(PPATH);
        }
    } catch (Error var3) {
        ;
    }

    String app_dataDir = app.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
    DexInstall.install(app, new File(app_dataDir + "/.cache_sdk/sdkclasses.jar"));
}
```

As far as my understanding the crash is because the system is failing to load the libraries.

My gradle looks similar as in the following link:

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/blob/master/Sample%20Code/app/build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

this issue has been fixed since 4.6 version of Android MSDK, pls try to update to the later version, right now the 4.7.1 has been released.